# edit name of input fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have many input fields in a table, each input field is like an index of an array like this

```
<input type="text" name="customproperty[0]" />
<input type="hidden" name="customproperty[0]" />
<input type="text" name="customproperty[1]" />
<input type="hidden" name="customproperty[1]" />
.
.
```

sometimes client delete fields and sequential order broken;

```
<input type="hidden" name="customproperty[0]" />
<input type="text" name="customproperty[2]" />..
```

I want all of them sequential so I call this method each time before post it;

```
function arrangeInputNames() {
    debugger
    var inptSlctr = $("#container");
    var allinputs = inptSlctr .find("input")
    allinputs.each(function (index, el) {
        var newIndex = Math.floor(index / 2);//since there is 2 element for each index
        el.name = el.name.replace("old name"," new name");//regex or ?
    });
}
```

I need such a regex or any smart business logic to change "only index numbers"
i mean the exp above changing shouldn't be "customproperty[2]" to "customproperty[1]" but "2" to "1" since property names always same only indexes can change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex, you can do :

```
el.name = el.name.replace(new RegExp("\[[\d]+\]"), "[" + newIndex + "]")
```

Comment: I upvoted yet. 
Someones downvote because in the chart, we have to show an effort of test, and not a free question like "i need something" or "how to do that" etc ......